# Can I sacrifice a creature that is only temporarily under my control?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A creature is placed "under my control until the end of turn" through a sorcery spell.

Do I have the option of sacrificing said creature if I cast a "sacrifice a creature" instant, or have a creature or enchantment that has a sacrifice ability?

Comment: A scenario that confused me once in actual play was stealing a creature equipped with Blazing Torch from my opponent.  Although the creature now controlled by me had the "Tap, Sac Blazing Torch" ability, it couldn't actually use it, because that would be sacrificing a permanent controlled by another player.  Much to my disappointment...

Comment: Gets even worse with older equipment cards where there are frequently abilities of the equipment itself, as opposed to newer ones that are generally worded to grant an ability to the creature!

Answer (score 21):

Yup.

> 701.16a To sacrifice a permanent, **its controller** moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control. Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: If you couldn't, spells like Act of Treason wouldn't be nearly as powerful. There's few greater feelings than stealing your opponent's big creature he hasn't even used yet to hit him with it, then sacrifice it on him. Hint: don't do that to your wife the first time you play with her, she won't play for weeks. [citation: personal experience].

Comment: [Grab the Reins](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=49435) would be the poster child for this answer. As it does both parts and does it intentionally.